# Can I use self-signed apps instead of using costly digital certificates in J2ME?

Tags: certificate, java-me, midp, digital-certificate

I have been using java since JDK 1.1.  Few days before I purchased one cheap Chinese Java enabled mobile for a mere US $ 33. I started learning midlets programing. After few small midlets I started to work on real geiger counter using mobile.

There are already many android apps on internet which use mobiles camera for this purpose. When camera lens is covered with black tape light can not pass through. But if any radioactive sample is kept near camera, beta and gamma rays pass through and camera sensors give some reading. Although you can not see picture, from alpha, r, g. b values you can co-relate actual accumulated dose. My idea is to take atleast 4 snapshots per second and take the average reading of 240 photos per minute to get a correct reading.

But this app needs permission to take snapshots and also I need write permissions, So, I have to sign this digitaly.

I came to know that min. charges for digital certificate from Thwate is US $ 129/- per annum and that of Verisign is US $ 331 per annum.

Unfortunately, My phone does not have any facility to add other root certificates as GoDaddy is giving certificates for only US $ 19 per annum.

Instead of spending so much, it's better to get Android mobile which I can get around US $ 90/- (MicroMax A 50). I have made sure that android apps can be self signed.

But before leaving J2ME for this reason, I would like to know if there is any way to run self signed apps.

I think all the J2ME developers should pressure Oracle to come out with a Java VM which will allow self signed midlets. ( Any way app is asking permission to the user )

Answer (score 0):

Some mobiles supports adding self signed.It is vendor and model dependent.

In Nokia s60 devices we can add self signed certificates which is used to sign midlet.

Nokia s40 device does not support self signed certificate.

Better you visit the vendor's website for further details

Comment: My model does not support self signed certificates. However, if there is some program available to read my phones internal memory and access it as a super user, it is possible to add new CA ( which will allow me to add self signed certificates as is done for Microsoft self signed Power Scripts )

Comment: user1445268 all phone vendors does not give the super user permission to the users(that is customers/phone users).So super user permission is not possible (Sometimes it is possible with some vendor.They provide some deivce for developement purpose with super user permission).